# Alamofire and SwiftyJSon get value outside request function

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swifty-json

Hey I am new here and I am trying to get value from request outside the request function in VC, but I cant do that I get errors I tried few ways, but I keep getting different errors, now I get Type Any has no subscript members, could you help me how to get string from request and find an array and take a value from it.

**I need to get value from Json strin in VC so I am trying this way:**

```
let retur = Json()
retur.login(userName: userName.text!, password: password.text!) { (JSON) in
    print(JSON)

    let json = JSON
    let name = json["ubus_rpc_session"].stringValue
    print(name)
```

**Response:**
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[0,{"ubus_rpc_session":"70ea230f29057f54459814459b5a316e","timeout":300,"expires":300,"acls":{"access-group":{"superuser":["read","write"],"unauthenticated":["read"]},"ubus":{"*":["*"],"session":["access","login"]},"uci":{"*":["read","write"]}},"data":{"username":"root"}}]}

**My request:**

```
  private func makeWebServiceCall (urlAddress: String, requestMethod: HTTPMethod, params:[String:Any], completion: @escaping (_ JSON : Any) -> ()) {


Alamofire.request(urlAddress, method: requestMethod, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { response in

    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        if let jsonData = response.result.value {

            completion(jsonData)
        }


    case .failure( _):
        if let data = response.data {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            completion("Failure Response: \(json)")

        }
```

Function which call request method:

```
public func login(userName: String, password: String, loginCompletion: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
let loginrequest = JsonRequests.loginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: URL, requestMethod: .post, params: loginrequest, completion: { (JSON : Any) in
    loginCompletion(JSON)
})
```

**Updated:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: you cannot do value["key"] on Any, your completion block need to return JSON [String: Any] or convert your Any block to anything you need inside function

Comment: I tried to change  value type here: completion: { (JSON : [String: Any]) in
    loginCompletion(JSON), but still on this line: let name = json["ubus_rpc_session"].stringValue , I get same error.

Comment: if you use [String: Any] it is impossible to still have error about "Any" check it again

Comment: btw if you want a json why are you calling responseString after request? Sting =\= [String: Any]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subscript with `Any` and after you converting `JSON` to `[String:Any]` if you are trying `.stringValue` with subscripting `Dictionary` then `Dictionary` doesn't have any property `stringValue` you are mixing two things here `SwiftyJSON` and Swift native type. I will access your `JSON` response this way.

First get clear about how you get value of `ubus_rpc_session` from your `JSON` response. You can't directly get value of `ubus_rpc_session` from your `JSON` response because it is inside the 2nd object in your `result` array,so to get the `ubus_rpc_session` try like this way.

```
retur.login(userName: userName.text!, password: password.text!) { (json) in
     print(json) 
     if let dic = json as? [String:Any], let result = dic["result"] as? [Any], 
        let subDic = result.last as? [String:Any],
        let session = subDic["ubus_rpc_session"] as? String {

           print(session)         
     }
}
```

---

If you want to work with `SwiftyJSON` then you can get value of `ubus_rpc_session` this way.

```
retur.login(userName: userName.text!, password: password.text!) { (json) in
     print(json) 

     let jsonDic = JSON(json) 
     print(jsonDic["result"][1]["ubus_rpc_session"].stringValue)
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, first way is working, but I want to do that with SwiftyJson, but I get error on print(json...) Type Any has no subscript members, there is the problem?

Comment: @EgleMatutyte I have already added answer for `SwiftyJSON` also, replace your method code with my one, **NOTE** You are passing completion handler var name to `JSON` change it to `json` and try like my answer.

Comment: I already tried, but still get error, check my question I added pic.

Comment: @EgleMatutyte Welcome mate :)